# Timer in android not correctly repeating on delay

Tags: java, android, service, timer, notifications

I have this code called in a Service:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
           public void run() {
               showNotification();
           }
      }, firstNotify, 86400000L);
```

It is my understanding that this should cause `showNotification()` to be called once per day at the same time each day, at the time specified in firstNotify (86400000 being the milliseconds in a day).

However, the notifies were happening approximately every 3 hours on my phone, and a little over 4 hours on my friend's phone. Is there any reason why these would be occurring faster than the specified 1-day period for repeating?

Answer (score 2):

I know its not a direct answer to your question, but you should use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) in such cases as yours. See [`setRepeating`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) function.

Comment: Thanks, I re wrote it using your suggestions and seems to be working great!

Answer (score 1):

If your `Service` is not setup correctly and it is being shut down at some point, the Timer would be recreated and called again after a `firstNotify` delay. Does this sound possible? You might be better off using [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to create the timed event.